# How to delete values from xml in NOTEPAD++

Tags: notepad++, xml

I have a large xml that has the below structure:

```
            <subform name="PRE_EC02_S1A">
                <field name="RIGA07">R7</field>
                <field name="RIGA08">R8</field>
                <field name="IMPOR20">I20</field>
                <field name="IMPOR21">I21</field>
                <field name="IMPOR22">I22</field>
                <field name="IMPOR23">I23</field>
                <field name="IMPOR24">I24</field>
                <field name="IMPOR25">I25</field>
                <field name="IMPOR26">I26</field>
                <field name="IMPOR27">I27</field>
                <field name="IMPOR28">I28</field>
            </subform>
```

I need to delete all the values from all of the fields. I can do it manually but as the document is very large it will take a lot of time. I would like to know if there is a way to delete them automatically. For example: I need deleted all the values like R7, R8, I20, I21 and so on

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested this with the sample you provided and it works in Notepad++. Open the replace dialog (Ctrl+H) and select at the bottom "Regular expressions". Then type the following: `([\>]).*([\<])` Replace with: `\1\2`

Edit: If you happen to have other xml tags with text inside you do not want to delete, if you want to empty only the field tags, then search for the following:

`([\<]field name[\=\"].*[\"\>]).*([\<]\/field[\>])`

Replace again with `\1\2`

Comment: Thank you John. It works just fine. You spared me a lot of time. Thank you again!!!!!!

Comment: You are welcome. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Another useful way of deleting data that is lined up as nicely as yours is using block selection. Hold you Alt-key while dragging with the mouse to select a square, (or alt+shift+arrow keys)then press delete.

Gif from Notepad++ feature description:

[image: demonstration]
<sub>(source: [notepad-plus-plus.org](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/assets/images/tips/columnMode.gif))</sub>

See more here: https://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/column-mode-editing.html